# Play framework, Scala: authenticate User by Role

Tags: scala, authentication, playframework

I've user roles: `user`, `manager`, `admin`. I need to authenticate them in controllers (methods). For example only `admin` can delete (now it looks like this, need to change that only admin should have permission):

```
def deleteBook(id: Int) = DBAction {
    findById(id) match {
        case Some(entity) => {
            books.filter(_.id === id).delete
            Ok("")
        }
        case None => Ok("")
    }
}
```

I've many controllers and methods. I need to authenticate before process request (for example deleting book). My `routes` file contains:

```
...
DELETE        /books/:id                  @controllers.Book.deleteBook(id: Int)
...
```

Some routes are only accessible to admin and manager. Some are for all types of users.

I'm currently seeing [deadbolt2scala](http://deadbolt.ws/) authorization module for play.

Can you recommend best way to authenticate multirole users in playframework scala?

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to do this by using StackableControllers provided by https://github.com/t2v/stackable-controller
Basically, I use a basic access control list provided by my application.conf. I start by checking if there is a user in my request. If there is one, I can check if he has sufficient access rights to perform the action.

Such a feature may be implemented using BodyParser composition too. I've never done that, though, so someone else's advice may be better for you.